# Any ways for implement YearMonthPicker?

Tags: wicket

I need some YearMonth Picker, with java.time.YearMonth , or mb Date/LocalDate with pattern yyyy-mm and year-month picker (like DatePicker without days pick).\
Are there any open implementations? Or idea what to take as a basis?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are different UI libraries that support year-month picking. In one project I used a JQuery plugin called [Zebra Datapicker](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker) which looks very nice and simple to use.  For example if you set format parameter to 'Y-m' you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: so, how i can integrate it with wicket?

Comment: You should take a look at the relative chapter of the user guide where you can learn fundamental concepts to integrate JS libraries into your Wicket app. You should easily adapt it to your specific case:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_an_example_of_integration_with_javascript